# How to find the saturation point and value from a given function

Tags: python, algorithm

I currently have a set of data as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The variable I defined, vibro_coeff, seems to approach a saturation value as time progresses. Now, I want to find an algorithm that allows me to obtain the saturation value and the corresponding saturation time.

The methods I have tried so far are as follows:

Use data fitting to obtain a polynomial.
Use this polynomial and define a parameter, err=0.0001. Start searching backward from t=70. If the average slope m of ten data points (1 second) is greater than err, then consider the system not in a stable state at that moment, and take the average value of these ten times as the saturation value.
However, it seems that this method does not yield the desired results.

Here is my code:

```
def saturation_cal(vibro_coeff) :
    err = 0.0001

    test = np.zeros(10)
    slope = np.zeros(9)
    ave_slope = 0
    ave_vibro_coeff = 0
    saturate_time = 0

    for i in range (0, 701) :
        test = [vibro_coeff[700-i] for i in range (10)]
        slope = [abs(test[i]-test[i+1]) for i in range (9)]
        ave_slope = np.sum(slope)/9
        if abs(ave_slope) > err :
            ave_vibro_coeff = np.sum(test)/10
            saturate_time = i/0.1-1
            break
        else : continue
    return ave_vibro_coeff, saturate_time
```

Could you please help me identify any errors or suggest a better approach?

Comment: *"it seems that this method does not yield the desired results."*: can you be concrete about that? Can you extend your code snippet with the code that initialises `vibro_coeff`, and calls the function? Can you add the *expected* result for that example, and what you get instead?

Comment: You could calculate the derivative and find the first large change (Or a peak in the second derivative).

Comment: Fitting the data is definitely a reasonable approach, but a polynomial is not your best choice of a fitting function.  As t increases your polynomial has to start increasing (or decreasing) again.  Given that your behavior has an asymptotic behavior you want a form that has a similar asymptotic behavior, e.g. tanh(a*t).

Comment: Alternatively, given that the behavior appears to be pretty linear up to the point where you reach saturation, you could average the last 50% of your data to get your asymptotic limit, then fit a line to all of the points up to when your get close to that limit.  The point at which that line reaches the asymptotic limit is probably a good estimate of saturate_time.

Comment: @Malcolm Changing the fitting function seems to be a good choice. But I think I will try something like A(1-exp(at)).